# Difference between const auto and auto for lambdas

Tags: c++

Is there any (useful?) difference between:

```
auto test = [..](..){..};
```

and

```
const auto test = [..](..){..};
```

?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, if the lambda is declared `mutable` then you cannot call it in the second case.

```
int x = 0;
const auto test = [x]() mutable { ++x; };
test();  // error
```

Comment: Is there any use-case for this?

Comment: @NeilKirk You mean for mutable lambdas? Of course there is, it's just like any other functor with mutable state.

Comment: Is there a use-case for ever declaring a lambda `const auto`?

Comment: @NeilKirk Not that I know of. For a non-mutable lambda there is no difference between `auto` and `const auto`. I wonder if `const` still aids optimization somehow. I don't know.

Comment: You also cannot move (effectively) a `const` lambda.  For lambdas that capture by move...